# Check if another user is logged in for messaging

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to find out if another user is logged in on a website using ASP.NET Forms Authentication?

- User A sends User B a message.
- if User B is logged on to the website, a popup should occur.
- if not, it will go to the usual notification page.

How can I go about implementing this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you have a list of "active sessions" in your database, it should know if a users login is currently valid, about to run out, or inactive.  If you have a script that is polling for messages, if a message is sent and it cant send, then the message goes to inbox, or, it shows on a screen.

Comment: Thanks for responding, at the moment i do not use sessions in my website, when a user logs in should i just place their user id in a logged in user table, does that make sense?

Comment: Well yes and no, if you dont use sessions, how are you sure that the person on the page is logged in? What if they share IPs? you'd surely be doing something with transitory data, also, how are you verifying then if they log out?

Comment: Hi i am using formsauthentication and cookies to ensure a person is logged in, so far this seems to work perfectly. On log out i am using the FormsAuthentication.SignOut() method.

Answer (score 0):

Normally some session variable will have been set with, for example, the logged in user id. Check if that exists, and if so, they're logged in.

I haven't used Formsauthentication myself though, so am unable to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this through the forms login and global.asax. If someone successfully is logged in, I add his/her username and session id in a dictionary in a application value, which is global accessible. If I get a Session_end in global.asax, I remove this entry.